# Export database from oracle to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, oracle11g

I have a problem where I need to send a copy of a database in oracle to database in mysql.

Does anyone know how I can do this please?

Comment: Do you want to copy only the data or do you want to copy both the data and schema?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Navicat Premium which let you connect and sync between SQL server, MySQL, Oracle... I'm using it and very happy with it if you don't want to do it by hand..

Comment: i transfer the data from one server to another, in one i have a script in php, in other one java application. i transfer the data by socket (this is a request of the client), and I had planned to do with generating a string data.

Comment: OK but what format for your string data ? csv ? piped ? other choices ? Also if it's a security matter, that software (and others) can connect through ssh / tunnels..

Comment: really do not know, i need export pragmatically the data, encrypt and send

Comment: Are you using a sort of webservice on the other end ?

Comment: in one server, one application init the process, one php script read the data from database, generate the "string" similar a export script, but not in a file, after that, send by socket, and client java read this data and execute the string with data to replicate the data os the database.

Comment: So what is your issue exactly ? Sending that data through socket ? Or generating it ?

Comment: My problem is how generate a string with inserts, and how generate this "string" in oracle and run in mysql

Comment: Are you saying you want to pass a oracle 'create' script like one does with a .sql script for mysql (Drop TABLE.. CREATE table.. Insert..)

Comment: Well then the php script should do that ! List tables, list fields, and in a loop do the oracle create statement

Comment: I understand, that is not possible automatycally, I would have to manually develop, i would have get the data and concat the insert instrucction, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used SQLyog for migrating data from oracle to MySQL.